# Compare the two values

Tags: calculus

It looks not too hard but actually really a challenge for me:

Given a function with two variables $f(x,y)\in C(I\times I)$,where $I$ denotes the unit interval $[0,1]$.Then compare the two values below and give a proof:
$$\inf_{y\in I}\sup_{x\in I}f(x,y)$$$$\sup_{x\in I}\inf_{y\in I}f(x,y)$$

I'v tried several examples but they are all trivially identities.How to make a function that make the strict inequality happen?I guess that will lead to a proof.

Thanks for help!

Comment: @DavidMitra I'm afraid it's not a continuous one...

Comment: @DavidMitra:I think $f$ should be continuous

Comment: Oh, didn't see the "C".

Comment: Take a diagonal strip of finite but small width centered on the line $y=x$. Define $f$ to be $0$ off the strip and $1$ on the line $y=x$. Let $f$ be "linear" elsewhere (the graph has two planar sections bounded by the edges and the center of the strip).